# Memory leak involving WSLogger class

Tags: memory-leaks, websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight 6.2 as a dedicated application server and have noticed that the class WSLogger corresponds to 85% of the total of my heap.

I'm using JVisualVM to get this information. I can also see that the used heap size is increasing and sometimes the GC runs and some memory is freed, however not all of that and the used heap size continues rising until it reaches the limit and a OOM occurs.

The operation we're trying to do is, starting the server and then using two devices, just do a sync on the data.

This issue only appeared after we migrated from Worklight 6.0 to 6.2.

Does anyone have any ideas from how could I continue to trace this issue? 
I don't have a garbage collector policy defined as a JVM argument, should I use the gencon one? (I'm using WAS Liberty Profile, with the Oracle JVM 1.7).

Answer (score 0):

What is your Worklight Studio 6.2.0.0 build number?
Check in Eclipse > Help > About > Worklight

WSLogger is not directly used in Worklight. WSLogger is a class of the WAS/Liberty runtime. This issue may be more related to another issue recently fixed.

August 18th saw a re-publish of Worklight Studio on the Eclipse Marketplace containing the aforementioned fix.

To install,

- Go to Eclipse > Help > Check for updates
- If you mean that you've actually installed Worklight Server on a Liberty application server instance, get the server components from IBM Fix Central website

Either way, try with this new build and see if there is any improvement.

Comment: I think I'm using said fix, IBM gave us these fixes to install: 6.2.0.0-WL-Server-IF201408121824.zip, 6.2.0.0-WL-StudioP2-IF201408121824.zip 
Unfortunately I think the problem persists and we're also investigating this issue, perhaps we'll figure out what part of the code is having this leak and find a work around.

Comment: Please try with this newer fix. Otherwise return to IBM with a question on this persisting leak; not much that can be helped in Stack Overflow if this additional fix is not having any positive impact.

Comment: What I was trying to see is if anyone has had this issue and fold a way around it. Perhaps even figuring out what on worklight calls WSLogger.

Comment: WSLogger is not directly used in Worklight. WSLogger is a class of the WAS/Liberty runtime. This issue may be more related to the fixes made in the August 18th release; please try with that build.

Comment: I have the studio up-to-date. Perhaps the build number is a couple of days early but it's the same fix. Do you know how I check if my WAS liberty is up-to-date?

Comment: Make sure you are not using 8.5.5.2 as that version is not supported. I don't know more than that. If the build from the 18th is not working, I do suggest to email your IBM contacts or open a PMR to have this recreated and debugged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59670/discussion-between-silva-and-idan-adar).